# Did the kids in Captain Planet have to be together in person to summon Captain Planet?

Tags: cartoon, captain-planet

In Captain Planet did the kids have to be physically together to summon him, or could they do it from their own countries?

Comment: Did the Planeteers have mobile communication devices? I can't recall. If not, they would need some way to coreograph the action of calling him without hearing each other or seeing the ring beams.

Comment: But where would Captain Planet show up then?

Comment: Pretty sure I remember an episode where the planeteers were separated and had to summon Captain Planet by all pointing their rings at the sun at the same time. I can't find it, though :(

Comment: @Xantec - 'Heart' enabled Ma-tii (however you spell it) to communicate with the others via a telepathic link. Bi-directionally, as in they could hold a conversation - making coordinating a call to Captain Planet whilst separated fairly trivial

Answer (score 6):

This depends on the range in which their ring powers (once released) can detect each other.  If I understand the shown procedure correctly, they all shoot the power from their rings up in the air, where they find each other and combine.  I'm not sure the furthest apart they've been in the series, but they don't have to be immediately adjacent.  Because their power goes up in the air, I'd imagine they could be quite a ways away, as long as they coordinate the action (say, over 2-way radios or telephones).  If I recall, they were all from different continents.  Could they summon him if each of them were home?  Probably, but it depends on how the power from their rings knows where the other powers are.
Captain planet would show up at the junction of the ring powers.